# How to specify other method for dist function in R?

Tags: r

In the documentation for dist function in R there's the following words :

method  the distance measure to be used. This must be one of "euclidean", "maximum", "manhattan", "canberra", "binary" or "minkowski". Any unambiguous substring can be given.

But I need to compute the distance based on a customized function that is not in the list, is there a way to specify it ? Or are there other ways other than the dist function that is suitable for my situation ?

I know I can do it in the lapply way, but I'm seeking for a neater way to do it.

Thanks.

Edit:

Th distance method I'm using is a correlation score using pearson distance. Is there a convient way for that ?

Comment: Could you give us an actual example? Depending on which distance measure you use, there might be non-lapply alternatives. But for adding one to the `dist` function, you'll need to adapt the C code.

Comment: `dist`is not hidden or intertwined to methods. So maybe just look at the code helps (type dist to your console and run it). Basically you could as well write your own function starting with what dist already does for / suits you.

Comment: @ran2 : the problem with that is that the methods are implemented in the C code, not in the R code...

Comment: @JorisMeys since he does not use the methods he might want to program to distance method by himself in R. Would be easier though if´d post some code or outline. Thx for the pointer anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't; `dist()` only knows how to compute certain distances. There are a good number of other distance/dissimilarity coefficients available in R packages via CRAN (including [vegan](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/index.html), [analogue](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/analogue/index.html) and the [proxy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/proxy/index.html) package, amongst many others.)

The latter, **proxy**, may be particularly suited to your needs. Not only does it have a large number of pre-specified coefficients, it provides a framework for specifying your own distance function that is then called from compiled code so is reasonably fast.

Comment: Thanks！The proxy package seems to be what I want !