# Is there a more efficient way to perform a function across sequential rows of a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I'm looking to calculate the [variation of information](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X06002016) between every row of a matrix with every other row of the same matrix. This distance metric isn't included in `dist` so I have to iterate through manually. Each row is a clustering and each column is a sample. The values of the matrix are {1,0} indicating whether the sample is a member or not of the cluster. Here is an example matrix and what I have now. It can take quite some time though, is there a more efficient way to perform this calculation?

```
# subset those clusterings which meet threshold of member count
m <- 100
n <- 70
membership <- matrix(sample(0:1, m * n, replace = TRUE), m, n)

# create distance matrix, set diagonal to 0
dist.matrix <- matrix(, nrow = m, ncol = m)
diag(dist.matrix) <- 0

# iterate through each row and calculate distances with subsequent rows
# fill values in distance matrix
for (i in 1:m) {
    for (j in (i+1):m) {
        if (j > m) break
        vi <- igraph::compare(membership[i,], membership[j,], method = "vi")
        dist.matrix[i,j] <- vi
        dist.matrix[j,i] <- vi
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to calculate a distance between each column of your matrix or each row of your matrix ?

Comment: Each row is compared with each other row, creating a square matrix with dimensions equal to the number of rows. Values on the diagonal are 0 since distance between two identical vectors is 0. Outer loop goes through all rows, inner loop goes from current row+1 to last row.

Comment: it seems you want to do distance measurement between your samples , am I right ? then you can do mn<- dist(membership, method = "euclidean"). The dist is a stat function which is basic function and you don't need any package. This is what you want?

Comment: That'd be fine if I wasn't using a different method, variation of information, which isn't included in `dist`.

Comment: If you need this often, implement it with Rcpp.

Comment: The answer to this question might help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482797/how-to-specify-other-method-for-dist-function-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use expand.grid to define the combinations, sapply to compute the values, and reshape to produce the final matrix

```
df_combs <- expand.grid(1:nrow(membership), 1:nrow(membership))
df_combs$compare <- apply(df_combs, 1, function(x) igraph::compare(membership[x[1],], membership[x[2],], method = "vi"))
df_wide <- reshape(df_combs, direction = "wide", timevar = "Var1", idvar = "Var2")
df_wide$Var2 <- NULL
```

df_wide is the same as dist.matrix.

Comment: It's a little cleaner, but seems to take longer.