# How to apply a function to array margin and create pairwise combination matrix

Tags: r

I am using R to apply a self-written function, that takes as an input two numeric vectors plus a numeric parameter, over column margins of data frame. Each column in data frame is a numeric vector and I want to perform pairwise computations and create a matrix which has all possible combinations of the columns with indicated result of the computation. So essentially I want to generate a behaviour similar to the one yielded by `cor()` function.

```
# Data
> head(d)
            1         2         3            4
1 -1.01035342 1.2490665 0.7202516  0.101467379
2 -0.50700743 1.4356733 0.9032172 -0.001583743
3 -0.09055243 0.4695046 2.4487632 -1.082570048
4  1.11230416 0.2885735 0.3534247 -0.728574628
5 -1.96115691 0.4831158 1.5650052  0.648675605
6  1.20434218 1.7668086 0.2170858 -0.161570792
> cor(d)
            1           2           3           4
1  1.00000000  0.08320968 -0.06432155  0.04909430
2  0.08320968  1.00000000 -0.04557743 -0.01092765
3 -0.06432155 -0.04557743  1.00000000 -0.01654762
4  0.04909430 -0.01092765 -0.01654762  1.00000000
```

I found this useful answer: [Perform pairwise comparison of matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22446825/perform-pairwise-comparison-of-matrix)

Based on this I wrote this function which makes use of another self-written function `compareFunctions()`

```
createProbOfNonEqMatrix <- function(df,threshold){
  combinations <- combn(ncol(df),2)
  predDF <- matrix(nrow = length(density(df[,1])$y)) # df creation for predicted values from density function
  for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
    predCol <- density(df[,i])$y # convert df of original values to df of predicted values from density function
    predDF <- cbind(predDF,predCol)
  }
  predDF <- predDF[,2:ncol(predDF)]
  colnames(predDF) <- colnames(df) # give the predicted values column names as in the original df
  predDF <- as.matrix(predDF)
  out.mx <- apply( X=combinations,MARGIN = 2,FUN = "compareFunctions",
    predicted_by_first = predDF[,combinations[1]],
    predicted_by_second = predDF[,combinations[2]],
    threshold = threshold)
return(out.mx)
}
```

The `predicted_by_first`, `predicted_by_second` and `threshold` are inputs for compareFunctions. However I get the following error:

```
 Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unused argument (newX[, i])
```

In desperation I tried this:

```
createProbOfNonEqMatrix <- function(df,threshold){
  combinations <- combn(ncol(df),2)
  predDF <- matrix(nrow = length(density(df[,1])$y)) 
  for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
    predCol <- density(df[,i])$y 
    predDF <- cbind(predDF,predCol)
  }
  predDF <- predDF[,2:ncol(predDF)]
  colnames(predDF) <- colnames(df) 
  predDF <- as.matrix(predDF)
  out.mx <- apply(
    X=combinations,MARGIN = 2,FUN = function(x) {
      diff <- abs(predDF[,x[1]]-predDF[,x[2]])
      boolean <- diff<threshold
      acceptCount <- length(boolean[boolean==TRUE])
      probability <- acceptCount/length(diff)
      return(probability)
    }
    )
return(out.mx)
}
```

It does seem to be working but instead of returning the pairwise matrix it gives me a vector:

```
> createProbOfNonEqMatrix(d,0.001)
[1] 0.10351562 0.08203125 0.13476562 0.13085938 0.14843750 0.10937500
```

Will you be able to guide me on how to make the desired pairwise matrix even if it implies writing the function code again within `apply()`? Also, if you could give me an idea on how to keep track of what pairwise comparisons are performed it will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you,
Alex

Comment: You might want to look into the **proxy** package which enables you to define your own custom function (like a distance function) and outputs a matrix.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7484202/2140956

Answer (score 0):

Your output gives you the result of the calculation in the order of the pairs in `combinations`: (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4). If you want to organise this into a symmetric square matrix you can do a basic manipulation on the result, e.g. as follows:

```
out.mx<-c(0.10351562, 0.08203125, 0.13476562, 0.13085938, 0.14843750, 0.10937500)
out.mtx<-matrix(nrow=ncol(df1),ncol=ncol(df1))
out.mtx[,]<-1
for (i in 1:length(combinations[1,])){
  a<-combinations[1,i]
  b<-combinations[2,i]
  out.mtx[a,b]<-out.mtx[b,a]<-out.mx[i]
}
out.mtx
```

which gives you

```
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 1.00000000 0.1035156 0.08203125 0.1347656
[2,] 0.10351562 1.0000000 0.13085938 0.1484375
[3,] 0.08203125 0.1308594 1.00000000 0.1093750
[4,] 0.13476562 0.1484375 0.10937500 1.0000000
```